# Pycaret Classification setup fails because 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names'

Tags: python, classification, pycaret

I'm trying to run this using PyCaret:

```
exp = setup(data = df,  target = 'CureFlag',fold_shuffle=True, session_id=2)
```

but I get the error that  'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names'.

Can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your scikit version is not compatible with the version of pycaret that you have installed. Please check and install pycaret in a new python environment to make sure the versions are consistent.